# Navigate in JSON with nultiple keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get a key from a `JSON` from a website using the following code:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = input('Enter url:')
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/json').text)
print(data)
print("####################################")
```

And here is the `JSON`:

```json
{"props": {
    "XYZ": {
        "ABC": [
            {
                "current": "sold",
                 "location": "FD",
                 "type": "d",
                 "uid": "01020633"
            }
        ],
        "searchTerm": "asd"
    }
}}
```

I'm able to load the page, find the `JSON`, and print all data. The question is, how can I print only the information from the `current` key? Will something like the following work?

```py
print(data['props']['XYZ']['ABC']['current']
```

Comment: current_value = data['props']['XYZ']['ABC'][0]['current']

Comment: @newbie, add that as an answer and explain OP that `ABC` key holds a list, hence the need to access it using an index.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have already explained, you need to add `[0]` between `['ABC']` and `['current']` because the value that corresponds to the `"ABC"` key is a list containing a dictionary with the `"current"` key, so you can access it with

```py
data["props"]["XYZ"]["ABC"][0]["current"]
```

---

Also, if you have a very complex and nested data structure and you want to quickly you can use [this set of functions](https://pastebin.com/NRxKRJPn)

```py
getNestedVal(data, 'current')
```

returns `'sold'`, and

```py
getNestedVal(data, 'current', 'just_expr', objName='data')
```

returns `'data["props"]["XYZ"]["ABC"][0]["current"]'` so that you can copy it from the terminal and use in your code. (It's not the best idea to use it other than for just figuring out data structure since it can use up quite a bit of time and memory.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access current like below:

```
data["props"]["XYZ"]["ABC"][0]["current"]
```

you can get a list of dictionaries by accessing "ABC" key's value.
So whenever you get curly {} bracket it shows that it is a dictionary and you can access value of particular keys using
`dict[key] or dict.get(key,default_value)`
and whenever you get square [] bracket it shows that it is list and you can access its element by  index `list[0],list[1]`.

So, accessing list element and dictionary's key's value is two different things. I hope you understood my point.